# Changing charset of a PHP file

Tags: character-encoding

For some reason, my Notepad++ doesn't allow me to change a file's charset from ANSI to UTF8-without-BOM : when I do it (Encoding > Encode in UTF8 without BOM) the file name in the top tabs doesn't become red as if I had applied no modification, and when I save the file and open it again, the charset is still in ANSI.

If someone can tell me what's wrong with Notepad++ here that would help. Otherwise, which free text editor can do this charset change very easily?

Comment: If the file doesn't contain any "exotic" characters, ANSI === UTF-8. So nothing really changes.

Comment: Perhaps you should use `Convert to UTF-8 without BOM`?

Comment: @deceze: nice theory. but in practice, Notepad++ does permit to change active encoding selection to `UTF-8` even for purely `ASCII` file.

Comment: @mvp But will it automatically *recognize* the file as "being UTF-8" when you open it again, or will it guess the next best available encoding?

Comment: @mvp : same result - deceze : what character could I insert to test this?

Comment: @deceze: for `UTF-8 without BOM`, it switches back to `ANSI` on restart, obviously. But I thought that @drake035 complained that it refuses to switch even as it is running

Comment: @drake035: @deceze is correct that if file is pure ASCII, switching to `UTF-8 without BOM` does not change its content, not a single bit

Comment: How can I make my file not pure ASCII to check this out?

Comment: @drake035: you can use `UTF-8` (i.e. with BOM), or just switch Notepad++ to UTF-8 mode and use any non-ASCII string, like this one: "привет" (hi in Russian).

Comment: I added this string, switched to UTF8 without BOM, saved, opened the file again : it's still in ANSI :(